# I fail installing maven on windows 7. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, maven

I try to install maven in windows 7 64 bit.
This is the path to the bin folder.

```
C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\apache-maven\src\bin
```

I am doing this:

1. Create System variable MAVEN_HOME with value :`C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\apache-maven\src`
2. Append to Path variable `%MAVEN_HOME%/bin`

This is the last part of the path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```

Edit: After doing this several times, when i get to cmd mvn  -version i get this error message: `JAVA_HOME not found in your environment`, this is the first time i get it, till now i got only invalid command, batch file not found

This is the path for java:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
```

1. I created JAVA_HOME with the value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0`
2. Append to the path variables: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

This is the last part of my path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

I am still getting JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.

Comment: You can add `JAVA_HOME` the same way you added `MAVEN_HOME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your JAVA_HOME to the home directory of your java installation folder (Assuming you already have JDK installed) .It should be something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24

Comment: I edited the question. I still can't figure out what i am missing

Comment: You need to add a new environment variable .Name it as JAVA_HOME and value as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0

Comment: This is exactly what i did :(

Comment: Did you try again after opening a new command window?

Comment: I was trying in the same command window. I opened a new one and now i get this: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Comment: Now this is a separate issue .Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305795/problems-setting-up-maven

Answer (score 0):

Try to download apache-maven-..*-bin.zip instead of the apache-maven-..*-src.zip from the maven download page. The bin folder should be directly under c:\apache-maven-3.0.4 directory. Set the PATH variable accordingly. Of course, add JAVA_HOME environment variable too.