# there is an error about libtool when building mesos

Tags: linux, mesos

When I build Apache mesos on CentOS 6.6 as the [guided](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/). But there is an error as follows.

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g1 -O0   -o libry_http_parser.la  libry_http_parser_la-http_parser.lo  -lz -lcurl -lsvn_delta-1 -lsvn_subr-1 -lapr-1  -lrt
/bin/grep: /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.la: No such file or directory
/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[6]: *** [libry_http_parser.la] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/mesos-0.21.1/build/3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty'
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/mesos-0.21.1/build/3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty'
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/mesos-0.21.1/build/3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/mesos-0.21.1/build/3rdparty/libprocess'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/mesos-0.21.1/build/3rdparty'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/mesos-0.21.1/build/3rdparty'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: @Skynet I didn't try to do it. It works well after I installed apr-util-devel. thanks all the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install all mandatory development libraries for this package. In this message it complains on lack of apr-util-devel.

I think

> yum install apr-util-devel

should help.

Comment: It's useful, thanks. Now it works well. But after that another error occurs.Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
make[1]: *** [java/target/mesos-0.20.1.jar] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/mesos-0.20.1/build/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: I don't know java at all, sorry, can't help with that stuff. Though, there are links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305795/problems-setting-up-maven and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l